# Month-end and weekend logic

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Pull the data month end and weekend without weekends.if get the weekend then retrieve the before that weekend.
Ex:the date is 20 or 21 Of AUGUST(WEEKENDS),Then i need the 19th(WEEKDAY) data..

Comment: MySQL <> OracleDB. Remove incorrect tag.

Comment: DOES THIS ANSWER YOUR QUESTION ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693357/8843451

Answer (score 0):

**O r a c l e**
You could use CASE expression with To_Char(Date_column, 'd').
The WITH clause is here just to generate some sample data and, as such, it is not a part of the answer.
Here is the answer including the order number of the day of the week ('d') and short name of the day of the week ('DY') because  **the day one of the week depends on NLS_TERRITORY.**
Here is the code...

```sql
 WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select SYSDATE - (LEVEL - 1) "A_DATE", 101 - LEVEL "A_VALUE" From Dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 18
        )
SELECT
    A_DATE "A_DATE",
    To_Char(A_DATE, 'd') "A_DAY_OF_WEEK",
    To_Char(A_DATE, 'DY') "A_DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME",
    A_VALUE "TBL_VALUE",
    CASE  WHEN To_Char(A_DATE, 'd') =  '6' THEN
             (Select A_VALUE From tbl Where A_DATE = t1.A_DATE - 1)
          WHEN To_Char(A_DATE, 'd') =  '7' THEN
              (Select A_VALUE From tbl Where A_DATE = t1.A_DATE - 2)
    ELSE
        A_VALUE
    END "VALUE_OUT"
FROM
    tbl t1
ORDER BY A_DATE
```

... and the result

```sql
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  A_DATE    A_DAY_OF_WEEK A_DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME  TBL_VALUE  VALUE_OUT
--  --------- ------------- ------------------ ---------- ----------
--  03-AUG-22 3             WED                        83         83 
--  04-AUG-22 4             THU                        84         84 
--  05-AUG-22 5             FRI                        85         85 
--  06-AUG-22 6             SAT                        86         85 
--  07-AUG-22 7             SUN                        87         85 
--  08-AUG-22 1             MON                        88         88 
--  09-AUG-22 2             TUE                        89         89 
--  10-AUG-22 3             WED                        90         90 
--  11-AUG-22 4             THU                        91         91 
--  12-AUG-22 5             FRI                        92         92 
--  13-AUG-22 6             SAT                        93         92 
--  14-AUG-22 7             SUN                        94         92 
--  15-AUG-22 1             MON                        95         95 
--  16-AUG-22 2             TUE                        96         96 
--  17-AUG-22 3             WED                        97         97 
--  18-AUG-22 4             THU                        98         98 
--  19-AUG-22 5             FRI                        99         99 
--  20-AUG-22 6             SAT                       100         99
```